# Why isn't my javascript from weather channel working?

Tags: javascript, drupal

I need to use the following code for a block in drupal-

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://voap.weather.com/weather/oap/BGXX0003?template=LAWNV&par=3000000007&unit=1&key=twciweatherwidget"></script>
```

Please someone help me how i should write the code. I have tried in php. But are not working.

```
<?php
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://voap.weather.com/weather/oap/BGXX0003?template=LAWNV&par=3000000007&unit=1&key=twciweatherwidget"></script>
?>
```

or

```
<?php
 drupal_add_js('<script type="text/javascript" src="http://voap.weather.com/weather/oap/BGXX0003?template=LAWNV&par=3000000007&unit=1&key=twciweatherwidget"></script>', 'inline');
?>
```

The javascript block is being used on a panel

Comment: Do you get any error messages? The script uses `document.write` for building the weather widget, so you have to put it in the exact position where you want the widget to appear. Usually scripts are included at the bottom of the page or something. There is an inline option for the `drupal_add_js` method, maybe that works.

Comment: Your first PHP example is totally invalid syntax, which may explain why it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

You should use external, also the script tags are not needed. Try the following:

```
<?php drupal_add_js('http://voap.weather.com/weather/oap/BGXX0003?template=LAWNV&par=3000000007&unit=1&key=twciweatherwidget', 'external'); ?>
```

More info about the drupal_add_js function at:
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7

Comment: Markkes this isn't working and i don't know why.I have added a screenshot in my question for your code. Thanks.Sorry can't post the image.

Answer (score 0):

It may be The Weather Channel that is the problem.

My Website (MinnesotaSeasons.com) uses this on all Destination pages. In the last 30 days they have been working only sporadically. Mostly, they just do not load. Before this there was no problem. The code has not changed. Only the results.

Here is the code I use for one of the destinations. It does not work this morning. It has in the past.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://voap.weather.com/weather/oap/55372?template=GENXV&amp;par=3000000007&unit=0&key=twciweatherwidget"></script>
```

Comment: In your case there is at least an error message saying it does not work, right? I think the problem is somewhere else.